# All contacts missing on icloud?

Tags: iphone, icloud

Suddenly, my iphone no longer has any contacts saved.

When I go to icloud.com, my contacts section is empty.

I tried: settings-> advanced -> restore contacts, but I see "no archives available".

Any suggestions for how I can troubleshoot this (or restore my contacts?)

Comment: Have you removed an Email account recently? Do you have a backup?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you may have removed an email or account that had all of your contacts stored! If this is the case, you need to try and get that account back on your phone!